# ActionScript 3: Get a File object's string value

Tags: actionscript-3

I have my Flash project properties set for: AIR 3.4 for Desktop and ActionScript 3.0...

I created a button for the user to select a file (csv) from the local drive. I then want to be able to get the string value of the File Object but do not know how...

Here is what I have so far:

```
BTN_CSV.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getCSV);

var myFile:File = new File();

function getCSV(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var docFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Documents", "*.csv");

    myFile.browse([docFilter]);
    myFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}


function completeHandler(event:Event) {
    var csvData = myFile.nativePath;
    csvData = csvData.data.split("\n");

    parseCSV(csvData);
}
```

I'm getting an error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method split through a reference with static type flash.utils: ByteArray. I don't know how to get the file path for the file obj...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file class is basically just a pointer to the file you want.
Your code is almost there you just need to add in the FileStream class.
[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#openAsync%28%29)

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.Event;

var file:File = File.documentsDirectory;
file = file.resolvePath("Apollo Test/test.txt");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCompleteHandler)
fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.READ);

function fileCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(fileStream.bytesAvailable, File.systemCharset);
    trace(str);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

[EDIT]

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.filesystem.File
import flash.filesystem.FileStream
import flash.filesystem.FileMode

var file:File =File.documentsDirectory;
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,onSelect)
file.browse()


function onSelect(event:Event):void{
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(file.size, File.systemCharset);
    trace(str);   
}
```

Comment: I've seen examples of this but what I'm not understanding is how this works with browsing for a file. All the examples I've seen already have a file chosen. Also, does File.documentsDirectory imply that the file is in that directory? I want the ability to chose a file from anywhere on my local drive.

Comment: Ok I made an edit for you. documentsDirectory is just pointing the File class to the My Documents folder on the local machine so when File.browse is called the opened window will be there kind of like a default location otherwise there is no telling what directory the browse window will be pointing to.

Comment: If you look closely I now posted to different ways you can access the contents of the file VIA a string.

Comment: The_asMan - That works perfectly!! Thanks for helping me understand the process better.